# Dual of the Ultraproduct of a Banach Space

Tags: ultrapowers, banach-spaces

Suppose we have a Banach space ultraproduct $(E_i)_U$.  I can think of three natural objects which are "dual-like":

1. $(E_i^*)_U$, the ultraproduct of the duals of the ground spaces.
2. The space made up of objects $(f_i)_U$ such that:

   a) Each $f_i:E_i\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$

   b) There is a $B$ such that for every $i$ and every $x$, $|f_i(x)|\leq B||x||$

   c) For any $(x_i)_U, (y_i)_U\in (E_i)_U$, $\lim_U||f_i(x_i+y_i)-f_i(x_i)-f_i(y_i)||=0$

   d) For any $(x_i)_U\in (E_i)_U$ and any real $\alpha$, $\lim_U ||f_i(\alpha x_i)-\alpha f_i(x_i)||=0$
3. The ordinary dual $(E_i)_U^*$.

It's easy to see that the space in (1) is contained in the space in (2) which is contained in the space in (3).  Furthermore, I think it's well known that (1) is, in general, strictly smaller than (3).

My question is what is known about (2).  Does it have a name?  I expect that it can be strictly smaller than (3), but are any examples known?

Edit: A little bit of motivation for why I'm thinking about (2).  It has some nice properties that (3) doesn't, since its elements can be described: given $f$ in (2), for each $i$ we have a function $f_i$ on $E_i$, and by choosing $i$ large enough, we can ensure that $f_i$ "resembles" an element of the dual of $E_i$.

But (2) should still act a great deal like the true dual.  (Formally, suppose $M$ is some model---say, of $ZFC$---where for every Banach space $X$, $\phi(X,X^*)$ holds, and which contains every element of our sequence $(E_i)$.  Then in $(M)_U$, $(E_i)_U$ is a Banach space, and $M$ believes that (2) is the dual of $(E_i)_U$, so $M$ will satisfy $\phi((E_i)_U,(2))$.  This may be enough for some purposes, or it may even imply that $\phi((E_i)_U,(2))$ holds in "the real world".)

Comment: Assuming that you mean the "Banach space ultraproduct" and not "ultraproduct of vector spaces" ... in 2. are you assuming that the $f_i$ are uniformly bounded on the unit balls of their domains?

Comment: If so, I think there might be spaces $E$ such that taking $E_i=E$ for all $i$, the space in (2) coincides with the space in (1), in which case it seems very likely that it will indeed be strictly smaller than the space in (3)

Comment: The answer to both your questions is yes (and I've rewritten the question to reflect that).

Comment: You need to be more careful in 2, I think:  Why do we have, if $(x_i)$ and $(y_i)$ are bounded families with $\lim_U \|x_i-y_i\|=0$, then $\lim_U |f_i(x_i) - f_i(y_i)| = 0$?  This is needed to ensure $(f_i)$ is well-defined as a functional.

Comment: For example, it would be enough to strengthen (b) to $|f_i(x_i)| \leq B \|x_i\|$ for each $i$ and $x_i\in E_i$.

Comment: Actually, having looked up the reference I had in mind, I retract the claim that there might be inf-dim spaces $E$ such that $E_i=E$ makes (2) equal to (1). There *might* be, but not for the reasons I was thinking of

Comment: @Yemon: Johnson's AMM paper?  Yeah, it doesn't seem to _quite_ do it...

Comment: @Matt: yeah, that was what I had in mind (you know me too well)

Comment: (!) is the same as (3) in some cases, such as when all spaces have a common modulus of uniform convexity, but they are different in general.  I have not seen (2) before.  

Comment: @Matthew: Yes, your version of condition (b) is probably the right one to use.